# Finding a Limit for Big Omega

Tags: limits, discrete-mathematics

I'm taking a discrete math course, and we were asked to prove that $2^n = \Omega(n^2)$. Trying to do that with big-Omega's limit definition, it leaves me with $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n^2}{2^n}$. How do I continue to evaluate this limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution which a professor for discrete mathematics may not like. You have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2}{2^n} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2}{2^x},$$

where we can think of $x$ as a continuous variable. Now we apply l'Hospital's rule twice and get

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^2}{2^x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2x}{2^x\ln 2} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2}{2^x(\ln 2)^2} = 0. $$

Note that you can only apply l'Hospital, because $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2}{2^x(\ln 2)^2} = 0$.

Informally speaking, your limit evaluates to zero, because $2^n$ grows way, way faster than $n^2$ for $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I didn't think of applying l'Hopital's rule in this context, but it turns out my professor did the exact same thing in her class. Is your solution comparable to

$lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{2x}{x2^{x-1}} = lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2}{2^{x-1}}$?

This also evaluates to 0, and follows the Big-Omega rule that $lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = c$ such that $\forall c, c \ge 0$  (as does yours, I'm just wondering if my proposed solution is accurate/legal).

Comment: No, the derivative of $2^x$ is always $(\ln 2) 2^x$. Notice that we derive with respect to $x$ and $x$ is in the power not in the base!

Comment: Oh, yes yes sorry. Thank you, much appreciated.